# How to create a networkx node with a colon?

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz

I need to create a graph using `networkx` (and `pydot2`) from data that I can't predict. I have a problem with the `:` character. If I want to create a node called `I like Python because : it's fast and readable`, `networkx` will create two nodes, one called `I like python because : it's fast and readable` and another called  `it's fast and readable`. It considers the colon as a node separation operator.

How can I avoid that ? Is there a way to escape the colon, or to tell `networkx` not to parse then ? The nodes are represented as strings (with the colon in them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the networkx 1.10 and everything works fine:

From a python interactive shell:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G=nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node("I like Python because : it's fast and readable")
>>> G.nodes()
["I like Python because : it's fast and readable"]
```

As you use a quote `'` inside the string use double quote `"` as string delimiter.

Comment: I need to do `G.add_node("\"" + my_string + "\"")` for it to work properly, `G.add_node("'" + my_string + "'")` doesn't work.